# Preg match a letter and number dependably

Tags: php, preg-match

How to make a preg_match in PHP for a string of 2 characters, for example:

```
1a valid
b2 valid
3c valid

11 invalid
67 invalid
ad invalid
dt invalid
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$string = "aa";
$result = preg_match('/^([a-z]|[0-9]){2}$/i', $string);
```

It matches everything instead of matching only if the first char is a letter and then a number and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^([a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])$/i', $string);
```

Comment: ah, damn i just had to double it

Comment: Oh. iirc, character classes (or whatever the ones between square brackets) match 1 character by default, so putting two side by side should match exactly two characters since I put `^` and `$`

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's how it works and why this answer is correct :p. `[a-z]` matches 1 character and `[0-9]` matches 1 character = 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Less readable than Rolando's answer, but slightly shorter

```
^[\d|[a-z][\d|[a-z]$
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/dXCDcb/4